# How to use codeigniter table update using mysql syntax like if condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to update records using mysql IF condition, is this supported as records are not updating

```
$this->db->update(
    'elections',
        array(
            'status'=>'IF(status=="Active","Inactive","Active")'
        ),
        array(
            'election_id'=>$election_id
        )
    );
```

I am getting following query on print:

```
UPDATE `elections` SET `status` = 'IF(status==\"Active\",\"Inactive\",\"Active\")' WHERE `election_id` = '8'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems CodeIgniter escapes your IF statement, but you can use it as string:

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE `elections` SET `status`= IF(`position`=?,?,?) WHERE `election_id` = ?', array('Active','Inactive','Inactive', $election_id));
```

Or
You can disable the auto escaping function (with set to false the third parameter of the set method):

```
$this->db->set('status', "IF(status='Active','Inactive','Active')", false)
->where(array('id' => $election_id))
->update('elections');
```

(Please keep in mind: in this case if your parameters can contain untrusted values you should escape them. e.g.: $this->db->escape)

Comment: My question is about db->update method, is there any way to perform same query using update method ?? writing queries is messy code

Answer (score 0):

Use a single equal (`=`) sign after status:

```
$this->db->update(
    'elections',
        array(
            "status"=>"IF(status='Active','Inactive','Active')"
        ),
        array(
            'election_id'=>$election_id
        )
    );
```